# How to redirect user if he is not logged in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a web application made in `.NET Core` with Razor Pages.

I'd like to redirect the user if they are **not logged in** to the login page. If they log in - the system should redirect the user to it's first requested link/original link.

This is my current `Configure`-method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)
{

    ...

     app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
     {
        await next();
        if(ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
          {
              //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
              string originalPath = ctx.Request.Path.Value;
              ctx.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
              ctx.Request.Path = "/error";
              await next();
          }
     });
     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseAuthentication();

     app.UseMvc();
```

}

So if a users requests /Dashboard/Settings/Account/Password for example and he is not logged in, I'd like to redirect him to the Login page first, and after he submits he will be redirected to that link instead of /Dashboard.

I am not sure how I can adapt this script ([source](https://joonasw.net/view/custom-error-pages))

#### edit

```
// In my login
if (result.Succeeded)
{
 _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    return Redirect(returnUrl);

  return RedirectToPage("/Dashboard/Index");
}
```

I think the problem lies here. My ReturnUrl is `null`. So it always redirects to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

What I did for cookie authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login/"; // auth redirect
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0 ); 
        });

    [Authorize] // set authorize will auto redirect to specified LoginPath
    public IActionResult yourmethod()
```

Comment: Does this also work with pages that do not exist? For example: '/Dashboard/Settings/Accounttttt'

Comment: I think it is better to respond with user friendly custom 404 page to avoid confusion. The link is invalid that point should be made clear.

Comment: However, if you want that behavior then make all 404 go to your home page with [authorize] set. If  logged in the user will see homepage else login page.

Comment: I understand, but I'd like to create a situation where users will be forced to login after proceeding to a specific url. And if they enter a wrong url -> it's a 404

Comment: Why do you want to force a 404 rather than a 401 ?

Comment: A 401 is also fine, as long as it's an error page. Like I mentioned above, I'd like to force users to authenticate before accessing a specific url. If in some other cases, the url is invalid they should see an error page - whether they are logged in in or not. I am not sure how to achieve this.